# Problems with redirecting because of a particular rewrite rule in the htacces file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I got a head breaking problem here. My redirects in the htacces- file won't work because of one particular rewrite rule. At least, that's what I think. The big question is how to solve this problem. I would be VERY thankful if one of you can help me out with this.

I want to redirect (301) the following URL:

"www.samplesite.nl/sample-2012.html"  to  "www.samplesite.nl/sample-2014.html‎"

Now normally I would have solved this by making a redirect rule in the htacces file as the following:

"RedirectMatch 301 /sample-2012.html(.*) http://www.samplesite.nl/sample-2014.html$1"

But when I do this on the htacces file of this website, I get the following URL in the browser

"http://www.samplesite.nl/sample-2014.html?html_name=sample-2012.html"

So basically the part "?html_name=sample-2012.html" shouldn't be in the URL to get this thing working like it should work for me.

Now here's the difficulty: In the htacces file, there's also a rewrite rule that is causing this, at least I think. It looks like this:

"RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).html$ page.php?html_name=$1.html&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]"

I didn't program this myself, but I think this rule is made to get the html info from my database into the page.php. The thing is, if I delete this (last mentioned) rule, the page is redirected alright. But then I get 404's on all my html pages. I have searched for a whole day, but could't find anything useful, or anything that seems like a solution. So I was hoping anyone over here can help me out. Looking forward to any comments what so ever.

Thanks in forward!!

Greets,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Try the redirect with a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^sample-2012.html(.*) http://www.samplesite.nl/sample-2014.html$1 [R=301,L]
```

R set the response, and L makes it the last rewrite (if matched)

Edit: And place it before the other rewrite, of course.

Comment: Hi Miquel, thank you VERY much for your quick and clear answer!! This seems to work very well;) You've made my day, dude. Is this solution also okay SEO- wise? Just like the redirecting I mean. Greets, Marc

Comment: This RewriteRule with R=301 is a redirect, just like the RedirectMatch you where using. It's 100% the same in every sense.

Comment: Hi Miquel, thanks again for your reply. I got all the info I need; ) Cheers!